# Hide cart when empty

Tags: php, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

Could someone help me with this syntax:

At the moment I have a simple link to my shopping cart like this:

```
<?php if ( is_woocommerce_activated() && isset( $woo_options['woocommerce_header_cart_link'] ) && 'true' ==     $woo_options['woocommerce_header_cart_link'] ) { ?>
```

And I want to add the condition to show my mini-cart when contents are greater than 0.  I found the code below, but I can't figure out where to put this condition in the line above.

```
<!-- <?php
    if ( is_woocommerce_activated() && sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) !== 0) {
        appply_mini_cart();
    }
    ?> -->
```

I would appreciate some guidance!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `AND` (`&&`) clause to the end of it.

```
<?php if ( is_woocommerce_activated() && isset( $woo_options['woocommerce_header_cart_link'] ) && 'true' ==     $woo_options['woocommerce_header_cart_link'] && sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) !== 0) {...}
```

Probably best to take a look at some of the PHP tutorials or documentation around as you will be coming up against this type of syntax regularly.

Comment: You're quite right Pieter - I keep coming short and getting errors because of my weakness in this area!  Thanks joersk.